# Acesso ao registro do windows por meio javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

No `IE` tem o `ActiveX` que me permite saber se um registro existe.

Será que existe uma forma para `Firefox` e `Google Chrome` que me permita saber se um determinado registro existe também (usando javascript) seja por meio de plugin ou outro método?

Answer (score 3):

Segundo [esta resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867689/writing-to-windows-registry-from-chrome-extension), para o Chrome não é possível.

No Firefox, a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Accessing_the_Windows_Registry_Using_XPCOM) diz que é possível através do [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM) usando a API [nsIWindowsRegKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWindowsRegKey) que foi introduzida no Firefox desde a versão 1.5.

Uma outra alternativa é usar um Applet Java para ter acesso mais completo ao PC, como em alguns sites de bancos que instalam software de "segurança".

Answer (score 2):

Com JavaScript, no Google Chrome não será possível aceder ao registro do Windows por questões de segurança. Talvez com ActiveX da Microsoft você consiga ter um pouco mais de permissão, mas JavaScript não foi feito para interferir no núcleo do sistema.